# How do I split string and return portion of string

Tags: python, string, split

New to Python - Trying to write a code/script that has user input an IP address and return the first 3 octets of the address, so I can add on more text to it.

Issue I am having is how to return the 3 octets the user has inputted correctly.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I have tried to split the string, and return it by using the join function, which works only if the string is an exact match.  So `10.10.10` will return correct string but `192.1.1` will not return correctly due to my print statement.

```
ip = input("Please enter an ip address with mask in CIDR format: ")
x = ip.split(".")

if "0/24" in x:
s = "."
s = s.join(x)
print(s[0:9] + "20 - " + s[0:9] + "191 is open range to use.")
    else:
print("something else")
```

so if user types in `192.10.10.0/24`

I want my return statement to be:

`192.10.10.20 - 192.10.10.191 is open range to use`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming the joined string is the same length regardless of input, which clearly cannot be the case.

By slicing the result of `split`, rather than the joined string, we can assure ourselves that we have only the first three octets, and *then* we can add on to it. Also, if you are using Python >= 3.6, you can use an *f-string* to better format your text.

```
ip = input("Please enter an ip address with mask in CIDR format: ")
ip_split = ip.split(".")

if '0/24' in x:
    result = '.'.join(ip_split[:3])
    message = f'{result}.20 - {result}.191 is open range to use.'
    # For Python <= 3.5, use this instead:
    # message = '{result}.20 - {result}.191 is open range to use.'.format(result=result)
    print(message)
else:
    print('something else')
```

Output:

```
Please enter an ip address with mask in CIDR format: 192.10.10.0/24
192.10.10.20 - 192.10.10.191 is open range to use.
```

Comment: Perfect, I did not realize you could join directly to the split portion of the string, which makes sense.

Comment: Thanks - and checking into F-strings!

Comment: @minty02 no problem - if my answer (or any other answer to any question you might ask) helped you, it might be good to accept it so that future browsers of SO can see what actually worked in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You just have wrong indents. Everything else works fine.
Just use this code:

```
ip = input("Please enter an ip address with mask in CIDR format: ")
x = ip.split(".")

if "0/24" in x:
    s = "."
    s = s.join(x)
    print(s[0:9] + "20 - " + s[0:9] + "191 is open range to use.")
else:
    print("something else")
```

Comment: Yes, thanks on the indentation, first time posting :)